# Octave - .m-File Compiler?

Tags: c++, matlab, compiler-construction, octave

I know that with **Matlab** it is possible to compile the scripts / functions as an executable which can then be a standalone version together with Matlab Compiler Runtime.

Is there any possible way to **compile .m-files associated with octave** as an executable program in a way that the .m-files aren't needed anymore for it to run?

I would like to a have a standalone version of the script (possibility together with octave libraries / dlls) without the necessity of the .m-Files.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is, see for example [How do I create a simple Octave distributable without installing Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843522/how-do-i-create-a-simple-octave-distributable-without-installing-octave), which references the relevant part of the documentation. However, I have never tried it, and it doesn't appear to be that straightforward (at first impression at least).

Comment: this solution still includes the need of the .m-Files, it doesn't work independently unfortunately

Comment: You're right, sorry. According to the wiki (not sure if it's up to date though), there is no equivalent to the MATLAB Compiler for Octave: http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#Compiler

Comment: That's right. @oszd93: What disadvantages do you see with the m-file solution? If you want to pack everything into one binary, there is probably a good solution. If you want the increased performance of native compiled code, there is no solution.

Comment: Its about packing everything in one binary without the necessity of passing on the m-File rather than because of perfomance-reasons.

Comment: @Daniel maybe you could tell me the solution you think about when talking about packing everything into one binary?