# Convert MATLAB M-file to stand-alone executable

Tags: linux, matlab, matlab-compiler

How do I convert a MATLAB M-file (.m extension) to a stand-alone executable without the help of MATLAB's Compiler Toolbox? I currently don't have the resource to purchase MATLAB Compiler Toolbox. Is there any other method?

Comment: There is no alternative to MATLAB Compiler. Your only option is to rewrite the code in a different language that you can compile with a freely available compiler.

Comment: Related but not quite the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24779199/octave-m-file-compiler

Comment: Oh ok @CrisLuengo

Answer (score -1):

If you're short on cash, you could ship your program as just a collection of `*.m` source code, and a launcher script that calls `matlab -batch my_main_function` to run it, and then your users are on the hook to buy their own Matlab licenses. Works as a program using regular Matlab as a runtime.

Comment: I do require it as .exe only and do not want the other party to purchase matlab license

Comment: Oh, sorry. Nevermind; you're SOL here! :)