# Octave feval: function not found

Tags: c++, octave

I'm trying to create a standalone executable in c++ using the octave libraries (http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs).  I've been following this process: [How do I create a simple Octave distributable without installing Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843522/how-do-i-create-a-simple-octave-distributable-without-installing-octave).

My problem- When I use my own script in feval, I get "error: feval: function 'my_m_file' not found."

How do I get feval to find my script? It is currently in the same directory as my executable.  Thanks,

Melissa

Comment: can you post the code you are trying to use? and the commands to build?

Comment: it doesn't if it's on the same directory as the executable. What matters is the current working directory, the one where you are when you start your executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `octave::feval()`. I recently had this problem in version 6.1.0 .