# Alternatives for Using MATLAB Files and Deploying Them into DLL's

Tags: objective-c, matlab, dll, unity-game-engine, octave

I have some source code for the BaNa Noise Resilient Pitch Detection Algorithm downloaded [here](http://www.ece.rochester.edu/projects/wcng/project_bridge.html), and I am planning to use the code they provided as a library for a mobile app I'm making. It's written in Objective-C for MATLAB and so I'd probably need to deploy it to a DLL to be able to use it for external applications.

The only thing is that I'm a student, and I don't really have the funds to purchase MATLAB just to be able to work with this algorithm, and so I'm downloading Octave, which was a suggested alternative. This should be able to make working and editing the code for my research possible, but my concern is if I can deploy the code into usable libraries for the application in which I'm going to make using the Unity Game Engine.

I'm not sure if the direction I'm going at will bring me to a dead-end or not, so I'd like to ask for insights regarding this.

What I have now: 
1) Source code in MATLAB (.m files)
2) Octave (currently downloading, I'm not even sure if it has the built-in methods I need)

What I plan to do:
1) Use Octave to edit code and test out if the code I have works 
2) Deploy it to a DLL file (Is this even possible with Octave?)
3) Use that DLL in Unity3D

Would you guys have any suggestions, alternative workarounds, or foreseeable problems I may encounter with this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance, 
Justin

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what functionality from MATLAB (and especially toolboxes), the code should run just fine in Octave, maybe with some minor modifications. If however, the code relies heavily on some toolbox functionality that has not been implemented in Octave, then you have a fair amount of recoding to do.

There is not easy way that I know of to generate a DLL from Octave. Having said that, have a look at [How do I create a simple Octave distributable without installing Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843522/how-do-i-create-a-simple-octave-distributable-without-installing-octave) and [this section of the Octave documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html) on the subject of generating standalone programs from Octave, it might point you in the right direction.