# How to use a Matlab function from a Python script on a machine without Matlab

Tags: python, c, matlab, visual-studio

## The setting

In a shared project I have written a Python script that needs to pass some parameters to a function a colleague wrote, receive its output and work on the results. Said function has been created in Matlab which I don't own (and which will not be available on the machine on which the final product will be running), so I asked them to convert it to an independent format.

What I received is a *.mexw64 file and a folder called "codegen" containing a whole lot of auto-generated stuff, among which is the wanted function as raw C code.

## The problem: C code does not compile

In order to use this new C function in Python I need to compile it, so I copied all the files into a freshly created project in VisualStudio 2015 and tried just that. It failed, as the function's parameter type "real_T" is not recognized. I have never worked with C and barely understand what I'm doing here, anyway, so right now, I am sort of stuck. My colleague has never exported anything from Matlab before and does not know what to do, either.

The original Matlab function looks like this:

```
function [a] = convert_vector(b)
  ...
end
```

while the resulting C code is the following:

```
/* Include files */
#include "rt_nonfinite.h"
#include "testc.h"

/* Function Definitions */
void convert_vector(real_T b[2])
{
  ...
}
```

## The question: How to compile C code?

In order to call C code from Python I need it to be compiled, but I don't know how to handle the "real_T" type error. Over at [MATLAB Answers](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49825-why-c-codes-generated-by-matlab-coder-contain-strange-data-type-like-real_t) they say everything necessary should be in the .h-file, but apparently VisualStudio doesn't know this, even though it is #included. This might all be me having never had anything to do with C and/or VisualStudio before, though.

However, I am wondering, whether this is the right way to go, anyway. It seems awfully tedious to convert to uncompiled C and perform a lot of operations on it  before being able to use a simple function. Maybe Codegen is not the best approach here?

## The higher-level question: How to export?

I've read that there are other possibilities to export Matlab functions, for example as a standalone *.exe file, which sounds way simpler to me both in terms of usage and module handling. So, I guess, the real question here would be: What is the best way to export the Matlab function in order to use it from my Python script, so that

- Matlab itself is not needed on the machine where the script is running and
- I can pass parameters and receive results via Python?

Sorry for this somewhat convoluted question. I am grateful for suggestions regarding every part of the problem, as well as hints on how to improve the question itself.

Comment: Is it possible to run the MATLAB code with Octave?

Comment: Yes, after installing a few packages, it runs fine in Octave.

Comment: If you think it you can expect your end-user to have octave installed on their machine, you can call the octave function directly from python using the `oct2py` module. Otherwise, your best bet is to have a look at creating c functions that make use of octave's API (https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Getting-Started-with-Oct_002dFiles.html) and adapt your c file appropriately.

Comment: I can expect them not to have Octave installed. Thanks for the tip about Ocatve's ''mkoctfile'', though. Trying to compile the given C file(s) fails here, as well (apparently some #included files are not actually in the package I've been given), but maybe it's possible to create a standalone file of the original function using Octave instead. Will update if this leads to a solution,

Comment: Update: It did. I followed the steps given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843522/how-do-i-create-a-simple-octave-distributable-without-installing-octave and the result is an *.exe file that I can call from my Python script. However, creating an executable with Octave is a long and tiring process that I can't really recommend as a solution, even though it fulfills its purpose as a workaround.