# Conversion of Matlab/Octave code into an executable file

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a function on image processing written in Matlab. I want to convert it into an executable file so that I can use that function in other applications. I tried Matlab coders, but since I'm using a Trial version, I don't have the Matlab Coder. What can be done? 
Can the same code written in Octave be converted into an executable file?

```
img2=rgb2gray(i1);
imshow(img2);
img3=imtophat(img2,strel('disk',15));
img4=imadjust(img3);
layer=img4(:,:,1);
img5=layer>100 & layer<250;
img6=imfill(img5,'holes');
img7=bwareaopen(img6,5);
[L,ans]=bwlabeln(img7);
imshow(img7);
I=imread(i1);
Ians=CarDentIdentification(I);
% Display the original image and the segmented image side-by-side.
imshowpair(I,Ians,'montage')
```

Comment: no, not in GNU Octave

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843522/how-do-i-create-a-simple-octave-distributable-without-installing-octave) for more info

Comment: The matlab coder is expensive. I suppose opencv is the only option. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well this works on Windows or Mac but on UNIX systems, I've been able to call my GNU octave scripts as executables by adding this line to the top of my octave script

> #!/usr/bin/octave

The "#!" gets picked up by your OS's program loader, and indicates that the following file is actually a script. The loader then looks to the given file path for the location of the interpreter. If your Octave interpreter is not at "/usr/bin/octave", you'd replace that section with the correct location.

After that you need to tell your OS that this script is an executable file. In bash you do that with this command.

> chmod +x octaveFile.m

This let's you call your octave script just like any other executable. In my case, I then called my scripts from python using subprocess.call('octaveFile.m').

Note that this is not a MATLAB or Octave feature. This is done by the operating system, so results may vary.