# How can I use GNU Octave commercially?

Tags: compilation, octave, obfuscation

How can I compile an octave program in order to sell it? The only octave compilers I've seen are for C programs with some of the octave functions. My objective is to obfuscate the code and ease exportability.

Comment: Interesting. At first I thought you wouldn't be able to hide your Octave source code without breaking the GNU license terms. But it seems that it is possible: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#IfInterpreterIsGPL

Comment: @CrisLuengo Do you know of any compilers or obfuscators for octave?

Comment: I don't know what the state of this is, it looks abandoned: http://strategoxt.org/Octave/OctaveCompilerDocumentation

Comment: @CrisLuengo: They had a funny roadmap. The goal was to basically have it finished in version 0.1 ( http://strategoxt.org/Octave/ReleaseRoadmap ) but 0.1 was never released.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer "How can I compile an octave program in order to sell it?". There is no equivalent to the MATLAB Compiler in octave. To deploy code you can [deploy octave for free bundled with your m code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843522/how-do-i-create-a-simple-octave-distributable-without-installing-octave), which eliminates most of the use cases for the MATLAB Compiler. 
This leaves the obfuscation, here the Matlab Compiler basically uses pcode. [There is no such thing in octave](https://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#How_do_I_run_a_Matlab_P-file_in_Octave.3F) which can obfuscate and run m code for you.

To answer the wider question of protecting intellectual property. There is the potential to obfuscate your Octave M code by removing comments, replacing variable names and so on, but to my best knowledge such a thing does not exist.

This only leaves oct file, which reading your question you probably don't consider an option. Oct files can only be created form C, C++ and Fortan code, not from Octave M code.

Please not that this is a purely technical answer and does not consider potential legal limitations imposed by GPL.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think my answer wasn't clear, reworked it. The answer to "How can I compile an octave program in order to sell it?" is a definite "There is no such thing in Octave", not a "I don't know".

Comment: Nice answer! Regarding Oct files: there your code links to Octave, which is GPL. Therefore, your Oct files must also be GPL if you want to distribute them. So that would not be a way to hide implementation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Good point, no clue about the legal situation. Added another sentence.