# Build a standalone Octave executable that can run on AWS EC2

Tags: compilation, octave, exe

We have a math model written in Octave that we'd like to run in the cloud - perhaps an AWS EC2 or ECS instance. The reason for this is that we want to feed in data from our database (ElasticSearch) and not be reliant on one person's machine to run the analysis. We're also trying to avoid rewriting the `m` files into Python or the like.

I've looked at the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843522/how-do-i-create-a-simple-octave-distributable-without-installing-octave) and find it hard to believe that there isn't a simpler way to compile an Octave script (with multiple files) into a standalone program that can be run in the cloud. Does anyone have experience doing this?

Comment: the main answer there is correct. As there is NO Octave compiler, and octave is an interpreter with a lot of compiled libraries you need to adjust your scope. In general a compiled program that uses the mathematical libraries of Octave will be much faster than your current program.

Comment: Why do you need an executable? You could easily install an octave instance, right? E.g., if you had a python file, presumably you'd need to install python on the server too, right?

Comment: "In general a compiled program that uses the mathematical libraries of Octave will be much faster than your current program." - that totally depends on where your program is spending its time. If the bulk of time is spent inside the number-crunching BLAS parts of Octave, then a program in a compiled language would not see significant speedup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Octave tool to do this. But I don't think you actually need it. As with other interpreted languages, like Ruby or Python, the typical way to deploy an Octave-based application is to install the Octave runtime (that is, Octave itself) on the machine that will be running it, and then deploy your collection of M-files to the machine and have it run those. Since you have control over your EC2 instances, this is doable.

(There are "frozen" Python applications that provide fully-packaged deployable applications with a bundled Python interpreter, or the Matlab Compiler for Matlab, but there's no Octave equivalent.)

Note that even compiled languages may require the installation of a supporting runtime. For example, C++ requires a C++ runtime (i.e. the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable on Windows, or the GNU or CLANG C++ libraries on Linux), Java requires a JRE, and "compiled" Matlab applications require the Matlab Runtime.

If you want a single-file way to transport your application to the server for deployment, package your application up in a ZIP file, copy that to the server, and unzip it at the installation location. Or you could package it up using your OS's native package manager, and have it declare a dependency on Octave.

The "one big installable package" approach in the other question you linked to is designed to solve the problem of distributing Octave programs to non-technical end users, on machines that the program author doesn't control. Presumably you have tech-savvy folks on your staff, and you control your cloud VMs that you're going to be deploying to, so you probably don't really have the same requirements.

You could also use Docker and build your application + Octave into a Docker container, for fully self-contained deployment.